# Reset wordpress all files and folders to it's default permissions

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions

I am using wordpress website on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server, by mistaken I have changed files & folders permission to 777 using File Zilla, Now whenever I try to update wordpress , plugins or anything in website I always get this error

[image]

I know this happen only because of file permissions that I have changed, Please let me know how can i reset all files & folders of wordpress directory to it's default which wordpress provides.

Answer (score 0):

Reset all permissions to 755 and everything should get back to normal.

(In FileZilla,

1. Navigate to the web root folder listing
2. Right-Click and select File Permissions
3. Type in numeric value 755
4. Tick Recurse into subdirectories and hit OK)